# .NET Core bluetooth

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm currently creating an application in .NET core. I want to run this application on a Raspberry Pi Zero W and use the Bluetooth functionality to communicate with an external device (Light Bulb with bluetooth). Are there any bluetooth (NuGet) libraries to work with bluetooth? I've searched on NuGet but I've found only Xamarin related packages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know it's not relevant to the question but I like to mention that .NET Core and .NET 5 do not support the ARMv6 architecture and therefore are not available on Pi Zero and Zero W. There are other boards in the same form factor as the Pi Zero but with better CPUs. One example would be the Banana Pi M2 Zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new dotnet-bluez library available that looks promising, and is pure .Net (not Xamarin).

https://github.com/hashtagchris/DotNet-BlueZ

Answer (score 2):

Not currently, as far as I'm aware.

However, I believe it would be possible if you explore using [Platform Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop) with the [Bluez](https://github.com/pauloborges/bluez) Bluetooth library for Linux.